# Are VLANs the same on different brands of devices?

Tags: vlan

I have 3 switches from different brand and I want to configure VLAN on them
Do these switches have to be from the same brand (Cisco or others)to be able to configure VLANs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem other than each brand of switch will use different commands (and different terminology) to configure VLANs.

To connect multiple VLANs between switches, all modern switches use the same IEEE 802.1q format, which mean they will interoperate with each other.

Again, the only potential problem is the terminology and procedures used by different manufacturers.

For example,

- On a HP switch you configure a VLAN and specify on which ports the
  VLAN should be tagged or untagged.
- On a Cisco switch, you first configure the port to allow VLAN tagging (Trunk mode). 
  Then you  specify which VLANs   should be allowed on the port.  You then also specify which VLAN should be   "native" (*i.e.* untagged).

EDIT:

Another potential problem is spanning-tree protocol.  There are different variations (some vendor-specific) of the protocol and you need to be sure you are using the same one across all switches.

(thanks to @Ronmaupin for reminding me of this)

Answer (score 2):

All vendors currently use VLAN tagging according to the [IEEE 802.1Q standard](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8403927). Apart from ancient devices using proprietary protocols, all interoperate nicely.

For things to work correctly, tagged links (VLAN trunks) must be configured in exactly the same way one both sides - one VLAN may remain untagged (sometimes called the *native VLAN*), all other must be tagged.

When combined with a spanning-tree protocol, there are some differences. Cisco's proprietary (R)PVST+ is also commonly supported by other vendors but it doesn't mix with any IEEE standard. From IEEE, there's the obsolete STP and current versions RSTP and MSTP, which are generally downward compatible.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no problem to have networks with multi-vendor hardware. Just be careful with proprietary protocols like EIGRP.

Comment: Are there any considerations that need to be taken if they are managed or  unmanaged?

Comment: @AbdAlrhman, you must have managed switches in order to use VLANs because unmanaged switches cannot be configured for VLANs. Also, you must make sure you configure the same spanning tree version on all the switches.

Comment: EIGRP is a routing protocol, not a switching protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem to use them together as VLANs are based on an open standard and your switches will work with them based on metadata in the headers of the frames. Just be careful of proprietary protocols of your switches. Cisco is full of them. It's necessary to disable them all in a mixed brand environment and just use open standard protocols. For example disable EIGRP and use OSPF instead.